# Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' when declaring a type in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am learning Typescript and following a tutorial, I wrote this code:

```js
interface Todo {
  text: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

type State = Array<Todo>;

const TodoReducer = (state: State, action: Actions) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "add":
      return console.log("add");
    case "remove":
      return console.log("remove");
    default:
  }
};

const Input: React.FC<Props> = ({ name, onChange }) => {
  ...
  const [todos, dispatch] = React.useReducer(TodoReducer, []);
  ...
};
```

But unlike the tutorial, in my case, I am seeing the error

> Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Pointing to

> 29 |   const [todos, dispatch] = React.useReducer(TodoReducer, []);

Comment: Just try to assign a default value for state `const TodoReducer = (state: State = [], action: Actions): State => {` also add a default case: `default: return []`. Currently your reducer does not return anything, assign some returns for both `add` and `remove` cases

Comment: Alright, it seems it solved. I wonder if it's due to a recent update because the tutorial I am following is only 3 months old. The catch was to add `: State =>`.

Comment: Apparently `useReducer` expects reducer to return something :)

Answer (score 1):

The TodoReducer must return a valid state for each case - event the default.

So something along the lines would work for your example to be valid. I did introduce a default state of an empty array `[]` and returned `state` for each action type. This you would have to adjust to your needs.

```
interface Todo {
  text: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

type State = Array<Todo>;

const TodoReducer = (state: State = [], action: Actions) => { // added a default state
  switch (action.type) {
    case "add":
      console.log("add");
      return state; // return your desired state
    case "remove":
      console.log("remove");
      return state; // return your desired state
    default:
      return state; // you did miss return state or similar here in your example
  }
};

const Input: React.FC<Props> = ({ name, onChange }) => {
  ...
  const [todos, dispatch] = React.useReducer(TodoReducer, []);
  ...
};
```